# What effect does $hidden have exactly in eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm  currently fiddling around with Lumen and Im using eloquent for my DB interaction. 
I've read through the docs of Eloquent and there was this explanation about hidden attributes:

Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes, such as passwords, that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do so, add a $hidden property to your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}



Alternatively, you may use the visible property to define a white-list of attributes that should be included in your model's array and JSON representation. All other attributes will be hidden when the model is converted to an array or JSON:
```

I don't understand what implications this has. If I have a query where a password is being inserted, should I hide it? Or will this cause the password not to appear at all inside my model instance?

For example, I have the following User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
  use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

  //protected $table = 'user';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'role'];

  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = ['password'];

  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I'm now running a controller which shall insert name, email, password and role of a new user into users table. 
Here you can see the table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3I2n.jpg

Now, when accessing my model to insert a new row like this:
User::create($requestData);

something goes wrong... 
The password doesnt get inserted.
I debugged the input, the data is there, the JSON String of the input right before the insertion takes place looks like this:

```
{"name":"tester1","email":"test.tester1@tested.de","password":"3627909a29c31381a071ec27f7c9ca97726182aed29a7ddd2e54353322cfb30abb9e3a6df2ac2c20fe23436311d678564d0c8d305930575f60e2d3d048184d79","role":"Benutzer"}
```

the password was hashed using php function `hash("sha512", $password);`. Its based on "12345", just for testing :D :P 
The hashed password has, as expected, the required length of 128 characters.

Any idea if this behavior is caused by the password attribute being defined as hidden in the model?

EDIT:
This is how I hash my password:

```
$requestData["password"] = hash("sha512", $requestData["password"]);
```

Comment: As far as I know and according to documentation $hidden fields are only hidden from JSON/Array representation. They are still present in model and everything else works normally.

Comment: Are you hashing the password attribute inside `$requestData`?

Comment: @Rwd Yes, see my Edit appended to OP!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason you're not using the built-in hashing mechanism i.e. `bcrypt` or `argon2`?

Comment: @Rwd Erm, bcrypt (or some variant of it) I tried to use, but as far as I could find, it didn't return the same result when called multiple times on the same input. Maybe I just screwed things up ^^ This way however, I didn't know how I would identify users against their stored passwords, if the hashed input doesnt match the stored hashed password xD

Comment: That's right, the hashing algorithms won't return the same hash every time. The idea here is that you would retrieve the user with a piece of unique data i.e. email address, and then use something like `Hash::check(...)` to see if the supplied password evaluates to the one you have stored in the database. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing#basic-usage (scroll down to **Verifying A Password Against A Hash**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The password won't get inserted as you don't have `password` in your `$fillable` array.

The `$fillable` array is to protect against mass assignment. If you are "filling" the models attributes from an array you will need to add the attribute name to this array.

That being said I would actually recommend you don't add `password` to the `$fillable` array and instead explicitly set the password on the model:

```
$user = new User($requestData);
$user->password = $requestData["password"];
$user->save();
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, the `$hidden` attribute is purely for when the model is cast to an array or converted to JSON so it shouldn't have an affect on inserts (or anything else).

Comment: How would the password explicitly be set without a function in the model , or what function would have to be called.

Comment: @logicalrap The example has: `$user->password = ...`. In this case, I'm explicitly setting the `password` property on the model instead of passing the value in an array and using the `fill()` method for mass assignment.

Comment: Now I get it thanks its working fine. I was forced to get rid of the create method when inserting details of the user because running the create first for other user columns and saving the password explicitly brought an error like "password field doesn't have a default value". Now all columns use the save method

Comment: @Rwd What security problems could arise if a password is placed in the `fillable` array? or why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @MrDave1999 It would depend on how you're setting you app up. If you use the `fill()` method (or one of the other methods that uses this behind the scenes) on the model to set its data and you also have `password` as a fillable property, then a user can potentially override the password which will be an issue if you don't have your model set up to handle hashing the password before it's persisted.

Answer (score 1):

protected $hidden is an array and is a Model class parameter, that what it does is hide that columns (in the array) from the database in the queries results. In your example, $hidden = ['password'] make invisible 'password' column in user results.

https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html 'protected array    $hidden The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.'